# explicit formula for a sum of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partial sum of rows of Pascal's triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69532/partial-sum-of-rows-of-pascals-triangle)

Working on the Euler characteristic of some topological space, I was led to the following situation. Let $a$ be a given positive integer and the sequence $u_i={1\over i!} \prod_{j=0}^{i-1} {(a-j)}$ can we simplify the expression $S_n=\sum 
\limits_{i=1}^{n}{u_i}$?

*Edit:* Working some examples I can see that  $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} u_i={1\over n!}\sum{\alpha_ia^i}$ such that $\sum{\alpha_i}=n!$ but i don't see the general expression of $\alpha_i$ . For example 
$$ S_2 = {1\over 2}a+{1\over 2}a^2$$
$$ S_3 = {5\over 6}a+{1\over 6}a^3$$
$$ S_4 = {14\over 24}a+{11\over 24}a^2-{2\over 24}a^3+{1\over 24}a^4$$
$$ S_5 = \frac{47}{60} a+ \frac{1}{24} a^2+ \frac{5}{24} a^3-\frac{1}{24} a^4 + \frac{1}{120} a^5 .$$

Comment: There's a $u_i$, and then there's an $a_i$. Make up your mind!

Comment: @J. M. : ok i made the correction. thanks !

Comment: $S_n$ is expressible in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function. Is that what you want? (I've gotten leery of posting closed form special function solutions after some past answers...)

Comment: $u_i$ is just the binomial coefficient a-choose-i, isn't it? So you're asking for the sum of the first $n$ terms in row $a$ of Pascal's triangle, right? Well, the first $n$ terms after $u_0=1$.

Comment: @J. M. : you mean $S_n$ is a polynomial with coefficients Pochhammer symbols wich in turn can be expressed using Gamma function ?

Comment: Gerry's right. $k!\binom{a}{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(a-j)$. Alternatively you'll see it expressed as falling factorials...