# A binomial like summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I need to calculate this summation:
$$\sum_{i=j}^m {m\choose i}  r^{i}$$
I know $\sum_{i=0}^m {m\choose i}  r^{i}=(1+r)^m$, but is there a nice closed form answer for the summation above?

Comment: There is a closed form for $r = -1$, but I do not believe that it is known for other values of $r$ (except for the obvious cases $j=0$ and $j=m$).

Comment: There's no closed form for it, but here are two links that can help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69532/partial-sum-of-rows-of-pascals-triangle http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n/17203#17203

Comment: The links are helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the last $m-j+1$ terms of the expansion of $(1+r)^m$, and I don't really think there's a nice closed form of that that just depends on $r$, $m$, and $j$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}r^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{m}{i}r^{i}+\sum_{i=j}^m \binom{m}{i}r^{i}=(1+r)^m$$
$$\sum_{i=j}^m \binom{m}{i}r^{i}=(1+r)^m-\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{m}{i}r^{i}$$

Comment: I don't think that's what is being asked. I agree it's true but it's not really a closed form and doesn't simplify the expression much.

Comment: I am not convinced that there exists such simple formula. Above formula make sense if $j<m/2$

Comment: I agree, it's one of those simple problem with no simple solutions.