# Upper bound on choosing at least $k$ items out of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form, upper-lower-bounds

I know from [Number of ways of choosing at least $k$ objects out of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353370/number-of-ways-of-choosing-at-least-k-objects-out-of-n) and [Partial sum of rows of Pascal's triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69532/partial-sum-of-rows-of-pascals-triangle) that given $n$ objects the number of ways to choose at least $k$ has no closed form solution. But is there a way to find a non trivial($2^n$ is a trivial upper bound) upper bound on the same?

Edit:

Found a similar question on Math Overflow that also answered my question. Here's the link : https://mathoverflow.net/a/17236