# Out of N switches, what is the formula for where the number of on switches is >= K with K <= N

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Out of N switches, what is the formula for the number of combinations with on switches `>= K`, assuming `K <= N`

It's basically

$$
\begin{pmatrix}{N \\ K}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}{N \\ K + 1}\end{pmatrix} + .... + \begin{pmatrix}{N \\ N-1}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}{N \\ N}\end{pmatrix}
$$

but is there a more concise version?

I rewrote it as

$\sum\limits_{i=K}^N \begin{pmatrix}{N \\ i}\end{pmatrix}$

$\sum\limits_{i=K}^N \cfrac{N!}{i!(N-i)!}$

N! $\sum\limits_{i=K}^N \cfrac{1}{i!(N-i)!}$

I know there's going to be N - K + 1 terms in the sum, so then letting

j = i - K

I rewrote the sum as

N! $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{N-K} \cfrac{1}{(j+K)!(N-j-K)!}$

But then I'm out, can it be taken any further? Perhaps even to a formula without a summing symbol?

Comment: Have you ever heard of hypergeometric series? I think the summation can be tackled by summing up the partial sum of hypergeometric with Gosper's algorithm.

Comment: Duplicated. Please refer [link]http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69532/partial-sum-of-rows-of-pascals-triangle